# Выровнять button по центру div css

Tags: html, css

Никакие `text-align: center;` не помогают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.calculator .container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#btnCalculator{
    display:inline;
    background: #008884;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1.7px 4.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    float: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Exo 2 M';
    height: 44px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 304px;
    font-size: 17px;

}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" id="btnCalculator">РАСЧЕТ СТОИМОСТИ БАНКРОТСТВА</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Уже сама разобралась, забыла убрать float: right;